# Using cURL with data.dol.gov

Tags: labor

Is cURL required for downloading data using data.dol.gov? Will the data.dol.gov API allow the API key to be embedded in the URL without using cURL?

Answer (score 4):

> Is cURL required for downloading data using data.dol.gov?

I'm not familiar with the data.dol.gov API, but I can't see how any API can require cURL (a set of libraries for accessing URLs).  You should be able to use any code, tool, or widget to generate your request (URL) against the API, and the API will respond accordingly.

> Will the data.dol.gov API allow the API key to be embedded in the URL without using cURL

The [beginners guide](http://developer.dol.gov/beginners-guide) provides an example with the API key in the URL:

`http://api.dol.gov/V1/DOLAgency/Agencies/?KEY=d9c6c290-da4c-424e-a378-fb4bd027b58z`

It's just an URL and you can just use it in a browser (no need for cURL); note, the key is just an example so you will get an unauthorized response.

If you want a command line tool other than cURL, you could probably use wget (see a [comparison](https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html) for details).  If you want to develop your own code, then see the [SDK developer](http://developer.dol.gov/sdk/) pages at the Department of Labor site.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code at http://developer.dol.gov/sdk/ or steal from it.

Comment: does that address the question? or just a blanket answer

Comment: Does one need to open a Bash shell and execute a curl command?  No.  At that site are several examples using different languages/platforms.

Comment: fair enough. but adding that to the answer would clarify